# crc table lookup not giving the same result as basic implementation

Tags: polynomials, information-theory, coding-theory, binary

The basic implementation of CRC uses XOR and left-shift operations to find the remainder. While the index of the leftmost bit of the remainder is greater than the degree of the generator polynomial, the bits of the generator polynomial are left-shifted until the index of the leftmost bit of the remainder is aligned with the leftmost bit of the generator polynomial, then the remainder is XORed with the generator polynomial.

For example, using one of the most common CRC-32, whose generator is the following generator polynomial (0x04C11DB7):
$$
x^{32} + x^{26} + x^{23} + x^{22} + x^{16} + x^{12} + x^{11} + x^{10} + x^{8} + x^{7} + x^{5} + x^{4} + x^{2} + x + 1
$$

Let's say the message is 101010 = 0x2A, then the remainder for this given message and generator polynomial would be:

101010 << 32

$\dfrac{101010 00000000000000000000000000000000}{100000 10011000001000111011011011100000}$

$\dfrac{001010 10011000001000111011011011100000}{001000 00100110000010001110110110111000}$

$\dfrac{000010 10111110001010110101101101011000}{000010 00001001100000100011101101101110}$

remainder = 1011 0111 1010 1001 0110 0000 0011 0110 = 0xB7A9 6036

Then if we go to https://crccalc.com/ and execute the CRC-32 algorithm on the same message, we get the result 0x09B9 265B.

Why are those two results differents? Is it normal that both algorithm do not return the same result? Am I missing something?

Comment: What you are missing are some additional steps done during checksumming. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks#CRC_variants . The initial portion of the data may be prepended or XORed by something (e.g. "all ones") or the output checksum is XORed by something (e.g. "all ones"). In fact, your link https://crccalc.com/ produces a number of variants of CRC-32, all of which have some tweaks of this kind. Perhaps the simplest is CRC32/POSIX, which only XORs the output with "all ones" and which produces 0x48569FC9 (i.e. your exact result XORed with 0xFFFFFFFF).

Comment: Also, the question is what is the "most significant bit" vs. "least significant bit" (i.e. is 0x2a checksummed as 010101 or as 101010 - reversal may mean the bits of the polynomial are also reversed!) In fact, have a look at https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/, in particular https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/17plus.htm. Also you may want to ask on Stack Overflow: as I think you don't have a problem with mathematical but with implementation issues.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is concerned with CRC-32 implementation issues, and so it is a better fit for https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: One last word: look at https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c#L149-L150 and you will see how the polynomial (after bit reversal) turned from 0x04C11DB7 into 0xedb88320.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CRC-32 or an implementation issue,the question is about the whole CRC, I simply used the example of a common generator polynomial, in the mathematical state of the CRC, we know that the coded message (Pc) is obtained by adding the rest of the euclidian division of the shifted message by the generator polynomial (Pg) to the shifted message, i.e.
Pc = Ps*Xr + (Ps*Xr mod Pg) where r is the degree of the generator polynomial. I just don't understand where does the XOR by something comes from?

Comment: That is what I meant when I said you know the mathematical side of things. The rest is just engineering "around" the basic algorithm, and as such is subject to specifications/standardization and details to do with practicality of the approach. E.g. prepending the bit string with 0xffffffff makes the bit string 0x2a and 0x002a have different checksums.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, it is just unclear about specifications/standardizations, should I delete my question?